# Mockito/PowerMock when....then not being invoked?

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermock

When I execute the following test, the original object is being returned and not the mock, so the real method **getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level)** is being executed (I observed that with the debugger). Why is that so? I'm pretty sure that this already worked yesterday and I didn't change anything there.

I already tried

```
@PrepareForTest({LevelCriteria.class, LevelGenerator.class})
```

or used the MockitoJunitRunner as I did before, but this doesn't help either. 
Here is the code (generateConcreteLevel is a private method. The expected exception is only thrown when I pass this data from the mock. Otherwise it's not thrown. The test fails because the exception is not thrown, because the test doesn't use the mock object but the real object):

```
 public class LevelGenerator
 {
    public void createLevel(int level)
    {
        generateConcreteLevel(levelCriteria.getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level));
    }

    private void generateConcreteLevel(LevelCriterion levelCriterion)
    {
        int entryGroupCount = levelCriterion.getEntryGroupCount();
        int exitGroupCount = levelCriterion.getExitGroupCount();
        int exitsWhileEntries = levelCriterion.getExitsWhileEntries();
        int maxGroupSize = levelCriterion.getMaxGroupSize();
        List<Question> questions = levelCriterion.getQuestions();
        int speed = levelCriterion.getSpeed();
        Range blueItemsCount = levelCriterion.getBlueItemsCount();
        Range brownItemsCount = levelCriterion.getBrownItemsCount();
        Range greenItemsCount = levelCriterion.getGreenItemsCount();
        Range redItemsCount = levelCriterion.getRedItemsCount();
        Range whiteItemsCount = levelCriterion.getWhiteItemsCount();
        Range timespanBetweenGroups = levelCriterion.getTimespanBetweenGroups();
        float fractionOfCarAmountToLeave = levelCriterion.getFractionOfCarAmountToLeave();
        float fractionOfMinimumItemsAmountInCarParkToStartExits = levelCriterion.getFractionOfMinimumItemsAmountInCarParkToStartExits();

        checkItemsFitInEntryGroups(entryGroupCount, maxGroupSize, blueItemsCount, brownItemsCount, greenItemsCount, redItemsCount, whiteItemsCount);
    }

    private void checkItemsFitInEntryGroups(int entryGroupCount, int maxGroupSize, Range... ranges)
    {
        int totalRangeCount = 0;
        for (Range range : ranges)
        {
            totalRangeCount += range.getMaximum();
        }

        if (totalRangeCount > entryGroupCount * maxGroupSize)
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error in level criterion: Not enough entry groups for Items.");
        }
    }
 }
```

and the test...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class LevelGeneratorTest
{
    @Mock
    private LevelCriteria levelCriteriaMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private LevelGenerator levelGenerator;

    @Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void tooLessPositionsInEntryGroups()
    {
        LevelCriterion levelCriterion = new LevelCriterion.LevelCriterionBuilder()
                                .withBlueItemsCount(new Range(10, 10))
                                .withEntryGroupCount(3)
                                .withExitGroupCount(3)
                                .withMaxGroupSize(3)
                                .build();

        when(levelCriteriaMock.getLevelCriteriaForLevel(anyInt())).thenReturn(levelCriterion);

        levelGenerator.createLevel(0);
    }
}
```

By the way: It's not an Eclipse problem, since a Maven build produces the same error.
**I know that I can execute the private method with PowerMockito's Whitebox directly what I will do after refactoring, but the question is, why when...then is not working here.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. Unfortunately you don't see the real problem in this question since I simplified the classes:

My real implementation of LevelGenerator got a parameterized constructor today. That's the reason why it worked yesterday but not anymore. Obviously there are mock injection problems with Mockito when not using a standard constructor.

Result: The when...then works as excpected.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question posted here, but a solution to your real life problem. ;-) Anyway I hope my answer did help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is:

> Why is the real method getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level) executed when I expect to have the mocked implementation?

I will try to demonstrate that everything works as expected fine if you reproduce it is a simple example (switch from your current workspace if you need to).

I do not have you `LevelCriterion.LevelCriterionBuilder()` so I simplified your test by just instantiating a `LevelCriterion` (empty object). This is not relevant because in my implementation I will always return an UnsupportedOperationException.

Here is how my LevelGenerator looks like. The UnsupportedOperationException is as simple as possible LevelGenerator#generateConcreteLevel(LevelCriterion).

If implemented like this:

```
public class LevelGenerator
{
    LevelCriteria levelCriteria;

    public void createLevel(int level)
    {
        generateConcreteLevel(levelCriteria.getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level));
    }

    private void generateConcreteLevel(LevelCriterion levelCriteriaForLevel)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("xxx");
    }
}
```

The test is green, using a `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on top of `LevelGeneratorTest`.

I did not used `@PrepareForTest` or `PowerMockRunner`. I have Mockito version 1.9.5.

I am sure that I have not used the real `getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level)` implementation, because it looks like this:

```
public class LevelCriteria {

    public LevelCriterion getLevelCriteriaForLevel(int level) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected call");
    }
}
```

If the real getLevelCriteriaForLevel(int) is excuted the test is red (because an IllegalStateException is thrown).

And the test is still green...

This works with pure-Mockito (version 1.9.5) approach.
You should remove all other mocking library (PowerMock, EasyMock...)

Are you sure that your static call of `when(..).thenReturn(..)` is the Mockito one?

Have you tried: `Mockito.when(..).thenReturn(..)`

I hope it helps.

PS: I have seen that you updated the question. It is a little bit unfair for me, but I am not going to update my answer once again.
I do not need the implementation detail of `generateConcreteLevel(..)` to illustrate that the `when(..)` call is working. Read my answer again. Try it in a separate workspace and you will see by yourself.

PS-2: I am using Eclipse too... Why should it be a problem? Eclipse is a great IDE.

Comment: Due to the data of LevelCriterion, generateConcreteLevel throws an exception. It does not throw an exception, when the real LevelCriterion object of the implementiation is passed. And that's the problem. Your example always throws an exception. It's clear, that it's always green then.

Comment: I need something in generateConcreteLevel(LevelCriterion) and my implementation is sufficient (TDD approach) to prove that what you are telling in your question is not true: "the real method getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level) is being executed (I observed that with the debugger)" This is not possible in my example because my real implementation of getLevelCriteriaForLevel(level) throws an IllegalStateException (if the code is excuted the Unit test will be red). Use the MockitoJUnitRunner as I told. Remove dependencies to PowerMock, EasyMock... and you will see that it works.

Comment: I updated the question. The result must be 10 > 9 => exception, but the original levelCriteria is used and not the mock, so the real levelCriterion is returned which doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: I have udpated my answer... I really hope you will figure it out by yourself. It is working as I described it!

Comment: I found the solution. See my answer.